# Как перенести локальный сайт (на WordPress) на другую версию баз данных (MySQL)?

Tags: mysql, wordpress, openserver

У меня есть новый сайт на OpenServer (на WordPress).
Я решил сменить версию MySQL, но из-за того, что я её сменил, я не могу войти в свою запись WordPress (которую я уже ранее создал). Мой вордпресс предлагает заново зарегаться в нём в новой версии MySQL

Это происходит из-за того, что я меняю версию MySQL (на старой версии MySQL у меня всё норм, а как только перехожу на другую то сразу вылезает файл Install.php).

**Я хочу узнать как мне перенести сайт на другую версию баз данных. Или как мне поменять версию самой базы данных, но оставить возможность заходить на сайт**

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/767562/233741

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.